# Warning: Error in result_create: no such column: tmp

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm running the database query by using `sqldf` in Shiny in R. But getting error.

***ui.R:***

```
  observeEvent (input$uploadForTest_1, {
    inFile=input$uploadForTest_1
    inFileName=input$uploadForTest_1$name
    file <-"tss.txt"
    tmp = paste("audio/street", inFileName, sep = "/")
    res <- read.csv.sql(file,header=FALSE,sql = "select * from file where V1=tmp",sep="\t")
    print(res)
  })
```

I'm successfully running the following query:

```
res <- read.csv.sql(file,header=FALSE,sql = "select * from file where V1='audio/street/b098.wav'",sep="\t")
```

But, if I run the query that is mentioned in `ui.R` it is giving me error that `tmp` column doesn't exists:

> Warning: Error in result_create: no such column: tmp   86:

I dont want to use string in my query. I want to use variable name. Because I don't want to hard code string in query. Can I use variable name in query instead of string. If yes, then how can I do this? I didn't find solution to my problem in Internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface `read.csv.sql` with `fn$`, and use `'$tmp'` in the SQL statement.

```
fn$read.csv.sql(file, sql = "select * from file where V1 = '$tmp'", 
  header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

See `?fn` and the gsubfn vignette for more info.  Note that sqldf automatically loads the gsubfn package so it will already be available.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sprintf`. Another option would be to paste together a string, but I find `sprintf` far more elegant for this task.

```
> tmp <- "audio/street/somefile.txt"
> tmp <- "audio/street/somefile.txt"
> "select * from file where V1=tmp"
[1] "select * from file where V1=tmp"

> sprintf("select * from file where V1='%s'", tmp)
[1] "select * from file where V1='audio/street/somefile.txt'"
```